# Android Studio - app crashes in other devices after renaming the package name

Tags: android, renaming

I'm using Android Studio. I have completed building my project. Then I had to rename the app name. So, I do change the project folder name and then I do change the package name with refactor and I changed the package name in manifest and build.gradle... Now when I run my app it launches perfectly in my device but when I do backup and send to other devices(via shareIt, bluetooth, any other means of sharing the app) the app installs and crashes while opening. Help me fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First Change the package name manually in the manifest file.
Then,
Click on your R.java class and the press F6 (Refactor->Move). It will allow you to move the class to another package, and all references to that class will be updated.

Comment: I have did that and the app launches and runs perfectly in the device that is connected to the laptop. But my problem is when I share my app it crashes while launching...